# Can I bundle a binary utility and call it from app?

Tags: android, command-line

Is it possible to create a app and call a command-line utility from it (bundled with the app), like it could be with a desktop application in linux?

Example:

My app wants to load some files but needs them to be converted, so first it calls an utility with command-line (like "jpgconv -r -t image.png") to create converted copies. Is it technically possible on Android?

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do is basically call the Android shell from your application and pass it a binary.

Android's shell doesn't seem to accept Intents, in which case it's not possible, and it's anyway severely limited, which is why most users  who need a shell (which is a very small subset of Android users) install a separate shell application, as well as tune their filesystem appropriately.

You could however try to embed your binary using the NDK, since, for exemple, BusyBox is straight C.

Comment: thx Kheldar, I am interested in running an open-source utility (like a console command), no data is directly passed except command parameters, just some file in the storage are processed/created by the utility. I think it is  allowed from GPL to distribute the utility with my app but  I have to call it via command-line to fulfill the license. Why do you talk about intents? (sorry, I am new to Android development)

Comment: Intents is the way Android programs communicate with each other (and even Activities inside a program). If you are that new to Android, you should read the well written Android documentation at http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html , it has everything you need to get up to speed.